# Misunderstanding about induced $\mathbf{E}$ field direction

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

Imagine a region in space that has a changing magnetic field through it. Two imaginary closed loops are "placed" in that region such that the two loops intersect with each other at different angles. This setup would mean that if you placed wires where the loops are, a current on different paths would flow in a different direction at the point of intersection (only 1 path is "active" at one time).

My question is this: To my knowledge the $\mathbf{E}$ field inside this wire is IN the direction of the induced current, for BOTH paths, meaning that in both situations the $\mathbf{E}$ field has a different direction at the point of intersection depending on which path you take.

Surely the direction of the $\mathbf{E}$ field is independent of whether or not a wire is present and is a property of the region involved itself.

What am I missing?

Comment: The presence of a wire does affect the E-field in its vicinity, as well as within it. As a simple example, imagine a conductor placed in a static external E-field. The charges induced on the conductor change the E-field such that it is zero inside.

Comment: so what what would the E field look like when no wires are present and just a changing magnetic flux? i know there is a curl of the field at each point but how does that curl translate to an actual vector arrow of the field?

Comment: user220348 i am aware that curl is a vector lol, that doesnt mean that the actual E field vector arrows are in the same direction as the curl...

Comment: You need to solve Maxwell's equations (not just the curl equation) with the relevant boundary conditions to get the E-field, which can be easy or very hard depending on the problem.

Comment: so given no PHYSICAL wire, the imaginary loops dr element doesnt have to he parralel with the E field, but changing it to a physical wire where charges move changes it to be such? (because when no wires present there must be a defined E field direction without a wire that might not neccesserily be in the direction of a imaginary loop)

Answer (score 1):

$\vec J$ is in the direction of the wire **and** in the direction of $\vec E$ inside the wire. This is because in each wire a charge distribution is formed that cancels the field component perpendicular to this wire.